# How to install PHP5.6 on OSX High Sierra without homebrew or macports

Tags: php, macos

I have upgraded from OSX Sierra to HighSierra which comes with Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.1 out of the box. For development I need to be able to use PHP 5.6 but have had issues with trying to run Homebrew (both with system Apache and Brew apache) and also phpbrew.

I also built PHP5.6 from source but think I need some additional steps to allow it to run alongside PHP7.1 as I ended up with the CLI version as 5.6 and the browser version as 7.1.

I have since removed the homebrew packages, and am back up and running with PHP 7.1.

So my question is - how can I install PHP5.6, without homebrew or macports and be able to switch between PHP versions either per-site, or globally?

Comment: i would just use a docker image

Comment: I did consider that as an options, however I've heard these can be a bit slow to run and can hog system resources. Still a valid answer, so thank you.

Comment: if you are on high sierra, the new docker doesnt need to run a base linux machine, it's a lot faster than it was before!

Comment: Do you know and did you tried https://php-osx.liip.ch/?

Comment: Yes, I've used this before. It's a good package, but whilst I can install it - I don't know how it will work alongside my current, and working PHP7.1 setup. This is the important part of my question as I need to be able to switch between versions.

Comment: I used this tutorial to set up the environment in my mac:
https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions
and in this, there is a script useful when you switching between different PHP versions, I actively using it:
PHP Switcher Script

Comment: That's using homebrew which I want to avoid. I had come across that article before and it's quite thorough.

Comment: @Mcload Ended up using your suggestion, although it doesn't answer my question, the article you liked to is brilliantly written and as such I have moved over to Homebrew for my work and both home computers. Thanks!